# Example of a group which is not a free product

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, infinite-groups

Is there a relatively well-known group $G$, such that the commutator subgroup, $G'$, of $G$ is a non-abelian free group, $G$ is not a non-trivial free product and $Z(G)=\{1\}$?

I know that trere are examples like $\left \langle a \right \rangle_2\ltimes F(b,c)$, $b^a=b^{-1}$, $c^a=c$, but I am interested in less obvious examples.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Obviously, I mean non-trivial free product.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Perhaps you are being a little over pedantic here? The direct product $G = F_2 \times C_2$, where $F_2$ is free of rank $2$ has $G'=F_2$ and has no nontrivial decomposition as a free product.

Comment: @DerekHolt I know that it is easy to think up an example. I am interested in unobvious examples.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have added to a question an additional condition, $G'\cap Z(G)=\{1\}$, to eliminate the most obvious examples.

Comment: But $G' \cap Z(G) = \{1\}$ in my example. In your question you said you wanted a "well-known" group, but in your comment you say you want a non-obvuious example. What does non-obvious mean?

Comment: @DerekHolt Something like Baumslag-Solitar groups.

Comment: But they don't have $G'$ free.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, I know, therefor I asked the question (and I have strengthened the condition to $Z(G)=1$).

Comment: The surface groups, like $\langle a,b,c,d \mid [a,b][c,d] \rangle$ are examples.

Comment: @DerekHolt I do like your last example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to record an answer, the hyperbolic $2$-dimensional surface groups, such as the torus group $\langle a,b,c,d \mid [a,b][c,d]=1 \rangle$ do not decompose as free products. It is well-known that all of their subgroups of infinite index, including their commutator subgroups, are free,

Comment: >It is well-known that all of their subgroups of infinite index, including their commutator subgroups, are free. I believe that subgroup H should be finitely presented, or in this case it is unimportant?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you are asking! The commutator subgroup is not even finitely generated.

Comment: I mean that the statement "A subgroup H of infinite index in this type of groups is free" requires H to be finitely presented.

Comment: No I don't think so. See for example https://chiasme.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/on-subgroups-of-surface-groups/